# Matrix contains values but still symbolic - Matlab

Tags: function, matlab, matrix

I have a matrix that is outputted like this:

```
maximums =

    [ -9.9043877608991468201413092380493, 426.34796945271797204125533010993]
    [  9.3758615553048990076305298649689, 441.87005169359418197397861057075]
```

But when I try and run any commands on it, I get an error saying that this matrix is still symbolic. I don't understand since it's just numeric values. Is there anyway of making this matrix outputted used by normal functions of Matlab?

To get this matrix, I did calculate derivatives of a symbolic equation and then evaluate. But I'd like to run functions on this output.
Thanks!

EDIT (Here's an example of the command/error):

```
[maxValue, rowIdx] = max(maximums(:,2),[],2)

Undefined function 'max' for input arguments of type 'sym'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert it:

```
maximus=double(maximus)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your matrix is symbolic, you have to [convert it to numeric](http://www.mathworks.se/help/symbolic/double.html) first:

```
maximums = double(maximums)
```